# Prompt the user to enter a week's worth of high temperature data. Store it in array. Find which day was the warmest and which was the coolest

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class TemperatureData {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Ask the user for the temperature and store it in an array
    System.out.println("Please enter a week's (7 days) worth of high temperature data: ");
    int weeksTemp = kybd.next();
    int[] temp = new int[weeksTemp];

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
```

//This is where I just am completely stuck. Help??

Comment: Start with defining what to read and what to print. I guess you don't have to change the number to read because "a week" is fixed.

Comment: Think about what you're doing; what comes next? (get the input data) So, you have a scanner and an array; use them. `temp[i] = kybd.nextInt();` You should also break this down into two questions since getting and storing the data is a separate concern from finding the high/low values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, you've to firstly store the data into the array which you are not. And then find the maximum value. Also, for taking numeric values, you don't use **next()**. You use **nextInt()** for integer values and **nextDouble()** for double values.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class FindMax{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner kybd=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 7 days\' temperature data");
        double temp[]=new double[7];
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
        temp[i]=kybd.nextDouble();
        double max=temp[0], min=temp[0];
        for(int i=1;i<7;i++){
            if(temp[i]>max)
                max=temp[i];
            if(temp[i]<min)
                min=temp[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Max temp : "+max);
        System.out.println("Min temp : "+min);
    }
}
```

This might be the code you wanna write. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not cycling through each array index asking for the input. What you should do is create a for-loop and each iteration asks individually for an input (each separated by a white space). Here is a quick example with your variable names:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);      //  declare scanner
    int[] temp = new int[7];        //  set array temp to a size of 7 ints to store an int for each day of the week

    System.out.println("Please enter a week's (7 days) worth of high temperature data: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; ++i)
        temp[i] = kybd.nextInt();       //  cycle through the array where each array index takes an input from the user

    for (int j = 1; j < temp.length -1; ++j)        //  sorting array
    {
        for (int k = 1; k < temp.length; ++k) 
        {
            if ( temp[k-1] > temp[k]) 
            {
                int tempSort = temp[k-1];       //  temporary int to store the value of the bigger integer bewteen two comparisons
                temp[k-1] = temp[k];
                temp[k] = tempSort;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < temp.length; ++k)   //  display sorted array
        System.out.print(temp[k] + " ");

    kybd.close();       //  close scanner once finished with it
}
```

Edit: I added a sorting array to my code. To answer your question, if the array is sorted from least to greatest, then you'll always know where and how to display your lowest and greatest temperature

Comment: okay so now how to I determine and print the high and low values?